# How do I send keystrokes/interative gui to another Win10 machine?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wmi, autohotkey, winrm

I'm currently using AutoHotKey to create a variety of macros. I have two desktops side-by-side in a private (home) network. **It is my desire to have the AHK `Run` command on `PC1`  make some sort of call to `PC2`.** Both PCs are running Windows 10 (non-domain), and both use the same login credentials (same account via microsoft.com).

**What I've tried:** I have tried a few things, such as WMI, WinRM, schtasks. Each of these options work when dealing with *non-interactive* scripts. I am trying to call scripts that a) open GUI windows or b) send key strokes to `PC2`.

**Other requirements:**

- The solution cannot require the password to be type in a prompt nor provided in the command-line call. The desired effect is that I press a button on my keyboard -> ahk command triggers -> script on `PC2` is called.
- As this network is shared with roommates (and whoever they allow to connect to our wifi), basic security is still a necessity.

This is not a language specific question - I am looking for the simplest/easiest/cleanest method. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try a remote access connection app like TeamViewer. They allow you to control one PC from another across a network. https://www.teamviewer.com/en/

I have an astronomical observatory in my yard with four computers connected to all the observatory equipment. These four computers are controlled over my home network from one PC in the house.

The remote access app allows you to run an .exe on another computer which in my case is usually a compiled AHK script.

I have a number of tasks that require several PC's. A script running on the main PC will start secondary scripts on the observatory PC'c which in turn will send messages back and forth by sending text files to each others shared files. The PC receiving the text file will perform a specific action based on the message.

Here's a link to the observatory startup procedure. I a startup script on the main PC which turns on all the observatory equipment then starts a secondary startup script on each of the observatory PC's to load and position all the software and then connect all the cameras and associated equipment.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UN4VoOKOcXo&feature=youtu.be

This just shows how the various scrips running on the observatory PC's load and position all the various app windows. Not exactly what you may need but it may give you some ideas about what you can do with the remote access software.

Lorence